# Binary operator > error

Tags: swift, swift3, double, cgfloat, operands

Im working on a game, in simulator works everything perfectly. But when I try to archive the project, I get an error on the line:

```
  if !shouldDetectScoreCollision && ballClearHeight.native > basketballHoopHeight {
```

error: binary operator > cannot be applied to operands of type cgfloat.native (aka float) and double (on ballClearHeight.native and basketballHoopHeight)

I have also couple of constants:

```
let halfBall = basketball.size.height/2.0
let ballClearHeight = basketball.position.y - halfBall
let basketballHoopHeight = 200.0
for i in 1 ..< throwPoints.count {
        // CGFloat.native is a Double
        dx += throwPoints[i].x - throwPoints[i-1].x
        dy += throwPoints[i].y - throwPoints[i-1].y
    }
```

I tried to convert basketballHoopHeight = Float(200.0), which gives me error: binary operator > cannot be applied to operands of type cgfloat.native (aka double) and float (on ballClearHeight.native and basketballHoopHeight)

And also tried to convert basketballHoopHeight = CGFloat(200.0), which gives me error: binary operator > cannot be applied to operands of type cgfloat.native (aka float) and cgfloat (on ballClearHeight.native and basketballHoopHeight)

However, when I convert let basketballHoopHeight = Float(200.0), the game works on the simulator, but gives the error when trying to archive.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ballClearHeight.native` is the value of the `CGFloat` in the
"native" type, and that is a `Double` on 64-bit platforms and
a `Float` on 32-bit platforms. Therefore neither

```
ballClearHeight.native > basketballHoopHeight // rhs is a Double
ballClearHeight.native > Float(basketballHoopHeight) // rhs is a Float
```

will compile for *all* platforms (as it is done for archiving).

So forget about the `.native` property and just compare `CGFloat` values:

```
let basketballHoopHeight: CGFloat = 200.0

if !shouldDetectScoreCollision && ballClearHeight > basketballHoopHeight { ... }
```